# FlatList numColumns is not showing results wanted

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

so i have food list data that i stored in JSON here :

```js
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "key": " Viande hachee",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/RuVD8qi.png   "

  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key": " Escalope pane",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/WNeYn6d.png"

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "key": " Escalope grille",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/iFpCySw.png"

  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "key": "   Cordon  bleu",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/iRo6ivZ.png"

  }
]
```

and here i have an interface which shows all the data one under other

[image]

So i wanted to show the results in a FlatList by grouping all items and putting them 2 under each other , this is the results wanted :

[image]

with FlatList props numColumns i thought i could make it happen but the results are completly different , this is what i get :

[image]

here is my code :

```js
const TacosData = require("./JSON/TacosViande.json")
class Te extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: TacosData,
        };
    };
    onchecked(id) {
        const data = this.state.data
        const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
        data[index].checked = !data[index].checked
        this.setState(data)
    }
    renderTacos() {
        return this.state.data.map((item, key) => {
            return (

                <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: 'center' }} key={key} onPress={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }}>
                    <Image style={styles.rednerImg} source={{ uri: item.image }} ></Image>
                    <Text style={styles.rednertext}>{item.key}</Text>
                    <CheckBox value={item.checked}
                        style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: 0.8 }, { scaleY: 0.8 }], }}
                        onValueChange={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }}
                        tintColors={{ true: '#D05A0B', false: 'black' }}

                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>

            )
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

                <FlatList
                    
                    data={this.state.data}
                    numColumns={2}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderTacos(item)}
                    keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
                />

            </View>
            );
    }


}
```

is there any solution ? how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your renderTacos function like below

```
  renderTacos(item) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: 'center' }} key={item.key} onPress={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }}>
                <Image style={styles.rednerImg} source={{ uri: item.image }} ></Image>
                <Text style={styles.rednertext}>{item.key}</Text>
                <CheckBox value={item.checked}
                    style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: 0.8 }, { scaleY: 0.8 }], }}
                    onValueChange={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }}
                    tintColors={{ true: '#D05A0B', false: 'black' }}

                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
```

RenderItem prop is used to render a single item and you have used a map inside it which is resulting in the above output, change the function like above.